# I have a list of dictionaries, how do I compare this to another list and separate the needed values?

Tags: python-3.x

Currently I have list of dictionaries which were taken from a CSV file. This file is in the form year,name,gender,number. I have made the list in the form

```
[{'year':'1991','name':'Aedan','gender':'M','number':'1267'},...]
```

I have another list of the years which I need to get the data for. I want to compare this list to the 'year' value of each list entry, if the years are the same I want to separate these out and then find the maximum 'number' for this year.
I have tried multiple things so far, all similar to

```
indices=[]
if data[i]['year']==years[j]:
    indices.append[i]
    i+=1
    j+=1
    print(list)
```

It produces no output

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: @DavideBrex I just added it, I forgot before

Comment: Why did you expect that this produces any output? Did you try to use `print()` to output something?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes I did, I just forgot to add that line to the code

Comment: You should never declare a variable with name `list`, it is a reserved word in python (to create a new list)

Comment: @DavideBrex Ill change that, ive had a bunch of different names so i just used a default one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this is what you want, but I tried in this way:

```
list_data = [{'year':1991,'name':"Aedan",'gender':'M','number':1267},
    {'year':1993,'name':"Ted",'gender':'M','number':22},
    {'year':1992,'name':"Mark",'gender':'M','number':1244},
    {'year':1991,'name':"Rachel",'gender':'F','number':1000}]
list_years = [1991,1992]
```

Then:

```
import numpy as np

for year in list_years:
    numbers_same_year= []
    for dictionary in list_data:
        if(dictionary["year"]==year ):
            numbers_same_year.append(dictionary["number"])
    print("Year: "+str(year)+" Max number: "+str(np.max(numbers_same_year)))
```

Output:

```
Year: 1991 Max number: 1267
Year: 1992 Max number: 1244
```

Comment: This code is exactly what I want thank you, but nothing is being appended to the list numbers_same_year. This is a similar issue to what has been happening with my other potential solutions

Comment: It means that the if condition is never satisfied. Can you check whether the years in `list_years` are actually also in the dictionaries?

Comment: They are definitely in the dictionaries, I also tested it with a range from 1990 to 2010

Comment: Ok..it's weird! Try to print (inside the inner loop) `dictionary["number"]` to see whether that may be the problem. Also check the type of the year variable.

Comment: ok so i printed it within the inner loop and nothing happened, then i printed it in the outer loop and it printed it for every dictionary entry, so i think the ```if (dictionary["year"] == year):``` loop is not being satisfied

Comment: I see..Another thing you can test is to print `year` and `dictionary["year"] ` before the if condition.

Comment: Both work, printing ```year``` prints 1991 and 1992 many times each and printing ```dictionary['year']``` prints every year in the dictionary

Comment: Then I don't know why the if condition is not satisfied, I am sorry. it's really weird. I hope that someone else can help you out. Last thing I can suggest is to double check that the years in list_years and those in the dictionaries are in the same format (integers). Good luck!

Comment: thank you for all of your help!! that was it, it was not an integer